# After Touch and hold on Scrollview than scrolling is not working

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, uiscrollview, scroll

I have build one application and use scrollview and add many subview to that scrollview dynamically all the thing is working scrollview is also working But when I touch and hold on scrollview after that scrolling is not working.

Please help me to out I have stuck on this problem.

Thanks in Advance for any help and suggestion.

**EDIT:**

I have find the problem but again it's new problem for me.

I have set the content size of scrollview dynamically like

```
if ([Array_Notes count] > 3)
{
    NSInteger no=[Array_Notes count] * 60;
    NSLog(@"%d",no);
    scroll_view.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 800);
}
else
{
    scroll_view.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 500);
}
```

So that the problem occurred (Touch and hold than scrolling not working)

BUT:-
when i have set the content size of the scrollview like

```
scroll_view.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 800);
```

Than its working fine without any problem.

So this is My problem any one have faced it?
Please help.

Comment: if possible please provide some more detail about project if you have added any gesture recognizers or tap recognizers ?

Comment: that is not the default action you might have disable the scrolling any where in your code...do you have any long press gestures or actions on scroll View sub views....

Comment: check whether you have given  scrollview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: Thanks all for the quick reply @AalokParikh I haven't add any gesture recognizers or tap recognizers in the project.

Comment: Scrollview user interaction is also Enable and I haven't use any gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

try setting this flag scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = YES;